Kostka-Jack numbers with the zero Jack parameter
Define the Kostka-Jack number $K_{\lambda,\mu}(\alpha)$ as the coefficient of the monomial symmetric polynomial $m_\mu$ in the expression of the Jack $P$-polynomial $P_\lambda(\alpha)$ as a linear combination of monomial symmetric polynomials. So this is an ordinary Kostka number when the Jack parameter $\alpha$ is $1$.
Let's denote by $\kappa'$ the conjugate partition of an integer partition $\kappa$. Then I observed the following equality:
$$
\sum_\kappa K_{\kappa,\lambda}(\alpha) K_{\kappa',\mu}(\alpha^{-1}) = K_{\lambda',\mu}(0).
$$
For $\alpha=1$, this equality can be derived from some results given in Macdonald's book. So I just conjecture it for $\alpha \neq 1$.

How to prove this conjecture, if it is true? (I'm ok for a reference)

Is there a nice interpretation of this equality?


